# Seeking C# code to convert Easting/Northing to latitude/longitude in GDA94 / MGA zone 56?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-rest-api

I am very new to GIS.

I'm pulling data from an ArcGIS Rest API service for a city in Australia to display as pins on a map in another system. The data I'm getting back has all the actual coordinates in x / y coordinates.

I've found that the x,y coordinates I'm getting correspond to the projected coordinate system with the "well known ID" of **28356**, which is apparently GDA94 / MGA zone 56 (see https://epsg.io/28356).

This seems correct and covers exactly the area I'm interested in. This web page on the Australian Government's Geoscience Australia website has an online form that confirms I've got the right coordinate system, http://www.ga.gov.au/geodesy/datums/redfearn_grid_to_geo.jsp

How do I convert these x/y coordinates into latitude/longitude in my own code?

Ideally, I'm after a function as simple as:

```
Coordinate ConvertFromGDA94Zone56ToLatLon(Coordinate source)
{
    // Magic code here
}
```

I'm writing in C#, if that's any help, but even if you can just give me the maths I can try and work it into code.

[ ...edit... ]

I've found the [Proj4](https://proj4.org) library and worked out that it can do what I need from the command line, but perhaps there's a .NET Core wrapper I'm not aware of...?

Comment: Deprojection math can be more than a little hairy. It's not suitable for newcomers (or even oldtimers). There are libraries which solve the partial differential equations involved, including within the AGS REST API, so I suggest you research how to request your desired spatial reference from the server.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing special about the Transverse Mercator projection which prevents implementation in your own code for conversion to lat/lon.  See this document for further guidance: [http://www.epsg.org/Portals/0/373-07-02.pdf#page=49](http://www.epsg.org/Portals/0/373-07-02.pdf#page=49).  Use a test point and it'll be fine.

Comment: Eventually managed to solve this on my own. The library I used is here: https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/ProjNet4GeoAPI, with lots of simple example code.